# Storing Check Box Selection in Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have programmed a Remember Me check box to store the username and password in cookies if the box is checked. My problem is, that if they check it and then re-launch the application the username and password auto fill, but the checkbox does not stay checked.

I have not figured out a way to do this yet...

I will post my code below:

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["UserName"] != null && Request.Cookies["Password"] != null)
            {
                userNameTxtBox.Text = Request.Cookies["UserName"].Value;
                passwordTxtBox.Attributes["value"] = Request.Cookies["Password"].Value;
            }
        }


if (chkBoxRememberMe.Checked)
   {
      Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
      Response.Cookies["Password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
   }

else
{
      Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
      Response.Cookies["Password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

}
Response.Cookies["UserName"].Value = myUserName

string passwordEncrypted = Crypto.Sha256(myPassword);
Response.Cookies["Password"].Value = passwordEncrypted;
```

The above code works as it should. But  I have a remember me check box that if it is checked I would like to save it to the cookies and leave it checked until the user unchecks it....

Any ideas?

Comment: you're doing this wrong. you should not store the password in plain text in cookies. That is incredibly vulnerable to attacks. you application should instead recognize the person as they enter the page (from some kind of encrypted token stored in cookies) and automatically log them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the checkbox should be checked by default any time the cookie is present, then I imagine you can just set its checked state here:

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserName"] != null && Request.Cookies["Password"] != null)
{
    userNameTxtBox.Text = Request.Cookies["UserName"].Value;
    passwordTxtBox.Attributes["value"] = Request.Cookies["Password"].Value;
    chkBoxRememberMe.Checked = true; // <-- here
}
```

Note that there are probably a couple of problems you're overlooking here...

1. If you always check the checkbox by default when the cookie is present, you don't give the user any way to *uncheck* the checkbox.  The user would need to manually delete the cookie from their browser, which isn't a very great user experience.  (Not to mention many users won't be aware of how to do that.)
2. Storing a user's password in plain text is ***grossly irresponsible***.  Please stop doing that immediately.  Instead, generate some kind of unique token to identify the user and store that token in the cookie.  The server-side code would then validate the token against known tokens associated with known users.  Never, *ever* store the user's password in plain text anywhere.

Comment: What about encrypting the password like I just did in my edit?

Comment: @codeBoy: What about not writing the password in the first place?  Any time a user's password needs to be stored server-side, it should be obscured with a *one-way hash* (this is *not* the same thing as encryption).  The general rule is that nobody, not even you as the system administrator, should *ever* be able to read the original password.  Encrypted things can be decrypted, so that's not good enough.  But even hashed, you shouldn't store it on the client machine.  It effectively defeats the purpose of having hashed it in the first place.  Just store a token, not the password.

Comment: There's no need to do that, codeBoy, when ASP.NET will do all that and more for you. You just to have invest a modest amount of time getting _ASP.Net Membership_ set up and then you ride on the shoulders of the Microsoft engineers who've already done the work getting this stuff implemented in a secure and reasonably intuitive way. See my answer for some info and links to the MSDN docs about how to do this without reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is what you're doing *terribly* bad in terms of security, you're also reinventing the wheel.

ASP.Net already supports out of the box Forms authentication, a default membership provider, properly encrypted/hashed authentication cookies and even a [logon control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login(v=vs.140).aspx) with [a remember me checkbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178340(v=vs.140).aspx)!

You would add the control to your ASP.Net logon page with markup something like this:

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginControl1" runat="server" CreateUserUrl="Register.aspx" 
 VisibleWhenLoggedIn="False" TextLayout="TextOnTop" RememberMeSet="True">
```

(We've set the [DisplayRememberMe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.remembermeset(v=vs.140).aspx) property to true. This instructs the logon control to display the "Remember me next time" check box and the membership provider to send the persistent authentication cookie to the user's browser upon successful logon.)

Before you start trying that however you should probably read ["Walkthrough: Creating a Web Site with Membership and User Login" on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c(v=vs.100).aspx).